# Why is my Stopwatch program not functioning?

Tags: java

I am trying to put what I learnt in multithreading to practice by designing a GUI stopwatch.

I was using Eclipse. I tried debugging also. In debugging mode when I pass the statement to change the text of the textfield it doesn't change the actual text in the output window.

What's more weird is that once in all these times my eclipse ide crashed, and the output window was open. Then the program was running.

This is the main Class which initiates two threads foreground,background through objects I and T respectively.

```
public class Coordinator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface I = new Interface();
        Thread fore = new Thread(I,"foreground");

        timer T = new timer(I);
        Thread back = new Thread(T, "background");

        fore.start();
        back.start();
    }
}
```

This is the thread class which keeps updating the text on the screen whenever a boolean variable 'changed' is set to true. Once it updates the text,it sets the value of 'changed' to false again.
It also manages the GUI. The GUI changes the value of a boolean variable 'Running' with the help of start,stop,and reset buttons.

```
public class Interface extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    JButton start,stop,reset;
    JTextField time;
    Container pane;

    String Reading;

    boolean Running,changed;

    long centisec;

    public Interface() {

        Reading = "00:00:00:00";
        Running = false;
        changed = false;
        centisec = 0;


        pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        time = new JTextField(Reading);

        start = new JButton("START");
        stop = new JButton("STOP");
        reset = new JButton("RESET");

        start.addActionListener(this);
        stop.addActionListener(this);
        reset.addActionListener(this);

        pane.add(time);
        pane.add(start);
        pane.add(stop);
        pane.add(reset);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String but = e.getActionCommand();

        if (but.equals("START"))
        {
            Running = true;
        }
        if (but.equals("STOP"))
        {
            Running = false;
        }
        if (but.equals("RESET"))
        {
            Running = false;
            centisec = 0;
            changed = true;
        }
    }

    private void updateReading() {

        int hour,minute,second,centisecond;
        long temp = centisec;
        String h,m,s,c;

        hour = (int) (temp / (360000));
        temp = temp % 360000;
        h = (hour>=10)?"":"0";

        minute = (int) (temp / 6000);
        temp = temp % 6000;
        m = (minute>=10)?"":"0";

        second = (int) (temp / 100);
        temp = temp % 100;
        s = (second>=10)?"":"0";

        centisecond = (int) temp;
        c = (centisecond>=10)?"":"0";

        Reading = h+hour+':'+m+minute+':'+s+second+':'+c+centisecond;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return Running;
    }

    public void incCentisec() {
        centisec++;
    }

    public void run() {

        setSize(2000,1000);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        for(;;)
        {
            if(changed)
            {
                updateReading();
                time.setText(Reading);
                changed = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setChanged(boolean changed) {
        this.changed = changed;
    }
}
```

This thread class keeps updating the data value of time in the variable with 10 milliseconds gap(only when 'Running' is set to true). After that it changes the value of 'changed' to true so that the other thread updates this new value to the screen.

```
public class timer implements Runnable {

    Interface I;
    public timer(Interface i) {
        super();
        I = i;
    }

    public void run() {

        for(;;) {
            if (I.isRunning())
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //  TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                I.incCentisec();
                I.setChanged(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output is a Stopwatch.
But my stopwatch doesn't respond to the buttons.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to use a capitalized reserved word as a class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the `volatile` keyword to the variable `changed`, as such

```
volatile boolean changed;
```

Sometimes, variables are cached in the thread and are not updated when it's changed by another thread.
This keyword forces the update of the value on each read.